# Adding a listener event to a ConcurrentQueue or ConcurrentBag?

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, semaphore, concurrentdictionary

I have multiple tasks that grab messages from a queue in a 1:1 fashion. I want to add these messages from each thread into a ConcurrentBag and process them as they come in asynchronously. The purpose here is to get messages off the queues as quickly as possible so the queues do not fill up. I just need help with a listener that waits until messages are added to the ConcurrentBag then I need to remove the messages out of the Bag and process them

```
private static ConcurrentQueue<string> messageList = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(50);
void Main (string[] args)
{
   List<Task> taskList = new TaskList();
    foreach(var job in JobList)
   {
      taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => ListenToQueue(job.QueueName));
   }
  Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
}


private async Task<string> ListenToQueue(string queueName)
{
   var cancellationtoken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)).Token
  
   //possibly 5000 messages can be on a single queue 
    while(!cancellationtoken.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
      var message = getMessageFromQueue(queueName);
      messageList.Enqueue(message); //Add the message from each thread to a thread safe List
     }
}
```

**I Need a listener event here that each time something is added to the list then this event will fire. Also I need to remove the message from the list in a thread-safe way.**

```
 private void Listener()
   {
      var msg =  string.Empty;
       while (messageList.Count > 0)
     {
         messageList.TryDequeue(out msg)
         await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            Task.Run(() => 
                  { 
                    try
                    {
                      if(!String.IsNullorEmpty(msg))
                      {
                     _ = ProcessMessage(msg); // I do not want to await anything but just fire and let it go
                       }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                       sim.Release();
                    }
                  });
      }    
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `Channel` instead of all this code? `await ChannelReader.ReadAsync` *is* a listener. Even better, `await foreach(var msg in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync()` will handle all items posted to the Channel asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days, I recommend going with an async-compatible solution like `System.Threading.Channels`:

```
private static Channel<string> messageList = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();

private async Task<string> ListenToQueue(string queueName)
{
  var cancellationtoken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)).Token;

  try
  {
    var message = await getMessageFromQueue(queueName, cancellationtoken);
    await messageList.Writer.WriteAsync(message, cancellationtoken);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // ignored
  }
}

private async Task Listener()
{
  await foreach (var msg in messageList.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
      _ = Task.Run(() => ProcessMessage(msg));
  }
}
```

But if you want (or need) to stay in the blocking world, there's a solution there, too. `ConcurrentBag<T>` and `ConcurrentQueue<T>` are seldom used directly. Instead, it's more common to use `BlockingCollection<T>`, which wraps a concurrent collection and provides a higher-level API, including `GetConsumingEnumerable`:

```
private static BlockingCollection<string> messageList = new();

private async Task<string> ListenToQueue(string queueName)
{
  var cancellationtoken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)).Token;

  try
  {
    var message = await getMessageFromQueue(queueName, cancellationtoken);
    messageList.Add(message, cancellationtoken);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // ignored
  }
}

private void Listener()
{
  foreach (var msg in messageList.GetConsumingEnumerable())
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
      _ = Task.Run(() => ProcessMessage(msg));
  }
}
```

Comment: oh thank you . So in the blocking collection example how is the Listener method fired?

Comment: You'd just call it. If you want it in a separate thread, then wrap it in `Task.Run`.